# When we say that "the internal energy (of the human body) has done work" then how does I'd relate to $F.ds$?

Tags: work

Basically the question, I am unable to show any effort put in on my part.

Answer (score 0):

When we say that the internal energy is doing work, what we mean is that the energy that was released after digesting the last meal you had was used to do work, an example should make it clear: Imagine typing this question, when you moved your hand the muscles near your fingers expanded (or contracted) to create a synchronised effort, and hence your fingers moved as you wanted then to.
More rigorously, the muscles near your fingers, applied a FORCE on your fingers, that caused them to move over and  press the keys on the keyboard, thus making a displacement, say s.
This will make you think that what I have written implies that our body can apply a force on itself (thus violating Newton's laws' basic assumptions), but, what we consider is only half the picture, your fingers exert an equal (and opposite) force on those muscles, making the *NET FORCE* on your body 0.